# Rails 4 association callback to update through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 models "Movie", "Person", "MoviePerson"

see active records for these models

**movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_persons
  has_many :persons, through: :movie_persons

  has_many :directors, -> { where 'movie_people.type =? ', "Director" }, through: :movie_persons, :foreign_key => :person_id, :class_name => "Person", :source => :person
  has_many :music, -> { where 'movie_people.type =? ', "Music" }, through: :movie_persons, :foreign_key => :person_id, :class_name => "Person", :source => :person
end
```

**person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_persons
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_persons
end
```

**movie_person.rb**

```
class MoviePerson < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled

    belongs_to :movie
    belongs_to :person
end
```

In rails console

```
2.0.0p247 :011 > m = Movie.last
 Movie Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies"   ORDER BY "movies"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  => #<Movie id: 7501, name: "Test", genre: [], status: "", shooting_location: [], plot: "", keyword: [], release_date: nil, url: nil, song_url: nil, created_at: "2014-07-22 03:58:48", updated_at: "2014-07-22 03:58:48"> 

2.0.0p247 :012 > m.director_ids = [Person.last.id]
Person Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people"   ORDER BY "people"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Person Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people"  WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 20685]]
Person Load (18.9ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" INNER JOIN "movie_people" ON "people"."id" = "movie_people"."person_id" WHERE (movie_people.type ='Director' ) AND "movie_people"."movie_id" = $1  [["movie_id", 7501]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
#<Person id: 20685, name: "Yansi", bod: nil, bio: nil, url: "", created_at: "2014-06-21 13:53:36", updated_at: "2014-06-21 13:53:36">
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "movie_people" ("created_at", "movie_id", "person_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-07-22 06:25:17.279331"], ["movie_id", 7501], ["person_id", 20685], ["updated_at", "2014-07-22 06:25:17.279331"]]
(9.5ms)  COMMIT
=> [20685]

2.0.0p247 :013 > m.director_ids
=> []
```

Here m.director_ids is returning empty array because not updating type of *movie_person* as **Director**.

How to use **association callback** to solve this?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html `after_add`

Comment: I tried after_add, but I want to update through model(in my case movie_person). Could you please give a sample code snippet..

Comment: I don't think you can do it through `movie_person`, you have to do it on the `directors` relation. You may also want to look into `accepts_nested_attributes`, it's a different way to do the same thing.